# SQL Convert Seconds into Day:Hour:Min:Sec

Tags: datetime, string, db2

Topic says it all. I'm trying to do some magic, via a function, that turns a second integer into a string "DD:HH:MM:SS".

*Snip*

input: 278543
output: "3D 5H 22M 23S  "

What I'd like to do, more gracefully if possible, is pad the numbers (So that 5M shows as 05M) and right align them so that "3D 5H 22M 23S  " is "  3D 5H 22M 23S" instead.

edit: Latest cut that seems to work. Would love to have it prettier, but this definitely works as far as I can tell:

```
CREATE FUNCTION DHMS(secondsElapsed INT)
RETURNS Char(20)
LANGUAGE SQL
NO EXTERNAL ACTION
DETERMINISTIC

BEGIN
    DECLARE Dy Integer;
    DECLARE Hr Integer;
    DECLARE Mn Integer;
    DECLARE Sc Integer;

    SET Dy = Cast(     secondsElapsed / 86400         as Int);
    SET Hr = Cast(MOD( secondsElapsed, 86400 ) / 3600 as Int);
    SET Mn = Cast(MOD( secondsElapsed, 3600 ) / 60    as Int);
    SET Sc = Cast(MOD( secondsElapsed, 60 )           as Int); 

     RETURN REPEAT(' ',6-LENGTH(RTRIM(CAST(Dy AS CHAR(6))))) || Dy || 'D ' 
         || REPEAT('0',2-LENGTH(RTRIM(CAST(Hr AS CHAR(6))))) || Hr || 'H ' 
         || REPEAT('0',2-LENGTH(RTRIM(CAST(Mn AS CHAR(6))))) || Mn || 'M '
         || REPEAT('0',2-LENGTH(RTRIM(CAST(Sc AS CHAR(6))))) || Sc || 'S';
END
```

Comment: is the input value reflecting time as a number of seconds?

Comment: yes. Updated for clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right track using LPAD(), since it can pad with zero or any other string. CHAR(15) is not enough to format the output the way you want and still allow five positions for the number of days, which is the length you specified in your code.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION DHMS(secondsElapsed INT)
RETURNS Char(18)
LANGUAGE SQL
NO EXTERNAL ACTION
DETERMINISTIC

RETURN LPAD( secondsElapsed / 86400 , 5 ) || 'D ' 
  || LPAD( MOD( secondsElapsed, 86400 ) / 3600, 2, '0') || 'H ' 
  || LPAD( MOD( secondsElapsed, 3600 ) / 60, 2, '0' ) || 'M '
  || LPAD( MOD( secondsElapsed, 60 ), 2, '0' ) || 'S'
;
```

Comment: Bad news is that part of my problem is that LPad doesn't work in DB2 (so question is a bit dishonest). Will edit question with what I've ended up doing to get it working. Your math parts definitely are more condensed. Also... "Create or Replace" doesn't work in DB2 either that I can figure... would be cooler if it did, as I have seperate drop/create calls that I have to run seperately.

Comment: Hello, what platform and version of DB2 are you running? The code I posted works on DB2 9.7 for Linux, UNIX, and Windows.

Answer (score 1):

declare @seconds int
set @seconds = 900000000
select cast(@seconds/86400 as varchar(50))+':'+Convert(VarChar, DateAdd(S, @seconds, 0), 108)