# T-SQL formatting Date arithmetic results in a friendlier format

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have some dates ...

```
1900-01-01 00:06:11.847
1900-01-01 00:09:12.097
1900-01-01 01:16:08.533
1900-01-12 20:08:04.453
1900-01-12 20:08:04.517
1902-12-30 04:58:52.500
1902-12-30 05:04:08.840
1903-08-30 21:03:07.187
1904-01-31 20:18:10.063
1904-04-02 06:05:52.313
1905-02-27 04:08:07.353
1905-04-02 22:08:07.377
```

As the result of a query ...

```
SELECT  ... GetDate() - [LastRunTime] as 'Age' ....
```

I would like the results to be in a friendlier, more human-readable format such as 1d 3h 17m 25s

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I probably wouldn't include the seconds in the final display.

Answer (score 3):

this will show you result in xd xh xm format:

```
select CAST(datediff(dd, [LastRunTime], GetDate()) AS VARCHAR(12))+'d '+
CAST(datediff(hh, [LastRunTime], GetDate())%24 AS VARCHAR(2))+'h '+
CAST(datediff(n,[LastRunTime], GetDate())%60 AS VARCHAR(2))+'m'
```

Comment: hmm, wouldn't this return all days, hours, minutes? For example, if the date difference was 1 day, it would return: `1d 24h, 1440s`

Comment: Ah I missed that. I've tested your query, and its fine, but the `GETDATE()` and `LastRunTime` need reversing or else you'll get negative values. Do you have any links to documentation on `%`? I've never seen it used in this context before

Comment: its called a modulo operator, check this link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%25_operator

Comment: Ah that makes sense. I was assuming it was somehow interacting with the previous data item, but its simply displaying the remainder when divided by 24, 60 etc.. Cheers +1!

Answer (score 1):

Your question has 'datepart' written all over it.

```
declare @t table(dates datetime)
insert @t values('1900-01-01 00:06:11.847')
insert @t values('1900-01-01 00:09:12.097')

select cast(datepart(day, getdate() - dates) as varchar(2))+' d ' 
     + cast(datepart(hour, getdate() - dates) as varchar(2))+' h '  
     + cast(datepart(minute, getdate()- dates) as varchar(2))+' m '  
     + cast(datepart(second, getdate()- dates) as varchar(2))+' s'  
from @t
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [DATEDIFF()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) would give you the period of time in a format of your choice.

For example, you could work out how many seconds are in between the 2 dates like so:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(s, [LastRunTime], GETDATE())
```

Then to get this into "days, hours, minutes, seconds", you could use a **User Defined Function** to return this as an `nvarchar`

This SO post should help you achieve this:

[SQL Convert Seconds into Day:Hour:Min:Sec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4694864/sql-convert-seconds-into-dayhourminsec)

Then you would do:

```
SELECT dbo.DHMS(DATEDIFF(s, [LastRunTime], GETDATE()))
```

**EDIT:** This solution will only work for dates which are less than 68 years apart.

Comment: This approach will only work if the difference for the seconds date part is less than 68 years otherwise an overflow error will be raised.